# Python's threads block on IO operation

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, io

I have the following problem. Whenever a child thread wants to perform some IO operation (writing to file, downloading a file) the program hangs. In the following example the program hangs on `opener.retrieve`. If I execute `python main.py` the program is blocked on an retrieve function. If I execute `python ./src/tmp.py` everything is fine. I don't understand why. Can anybody explain me what is happening?

I am using python2.7 on Linux system (kernel 3.5.0-27).

File ordering:

```
main.py
./src
    __init__.py
    tmp.py
```

main.py

```
import src.tmp
```

tmp.py

```
import threading
import urllib

class DownloaderThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, pool_sema, i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.pool_sema  = pool_sema
        self.daemon     = True
        self.i = i

    def run(self):
        try:
            opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({}) 
            opener.retrieve("http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy.pdf", "/tmp/" + str(self.i) + ".pdf")
        finally:
            self.pool_sema.release()

class Downloader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        maxthreads             = 1
        self.pool_sema         = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=maxthreads)

    def download_folder(self):
        for i in xrange(20):
            self.pool_sema.acquire()
            print "Downloading", i
            t = DownloaderThread(self.pool_sema,i)
            t.start()

d = Downloader()
d.download_folder()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by hacking `urllib.py` - if you inspect it you will see many `import` statements dispersed within the code - i.e. it uses imports stuff 'on the fly' and not just when the module loads.

So, the *real* reason is still unknown - but not worth investigating - probably some deadlock in Python's import system. You just shouldn't run nontrivial code during an `import` - that's just asking for trouble.

If you insist, you can get it to work if you move all these weird import statements to the beginning of urllib.py.